Does Iceberg table compaction combine small row groups into larger ones?
The posts I've been able to find that describe Iceberg compaction only talk about combining small (parquet) files into larger ones.
But a single parquet file is itself comprised of row-groups (more info), and the size of row-groups impacts various things such as how the file is read (by Spark, Presto etc), file compression, etc (more info) so being able to control this is useful.
So, does Iceberg combine smaller row-groups into larger ones?  And does it allow for control of row-group size?
It's unclear from what I've been able to find online whether it combines files but leaves row-groups as they were in the original files, or if each new file consists of just a single row-group, or if it's something else.
